# Write the equation that results in the desired transformation

Tags: graphing-functions, transformational-geometry

The cubing function, vertically shrunk by a factor of $0.2$, and reflected the $x$-axis then $y=$?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin haha I'm so far behind as far as math goes. I'm probably at a 7th grade level but I'm in college algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Notice

when a given function say $y=f(x)$ is vertically shrunk (scaled down/scaled up) by a factor $k$ its transformed equation is given as $$y_1=kf(x)$$

Now, the function $y_1=kf(x)$ is reflected about the x-axis, the transformed equation is given as $$y_2=-kf(x)$$